# How do I pray jamaat with my husband and brother in-law ( husbands brother)?

Tags: jamaat

What is the right way to pray jamaat with my husband leading the prayer. My brother in law usually stands beside him and I pray right behind my brother in law. Is that okay ? Or should I just stand behind my husband whether he is leading the prayer or not ?

Also, since my brother in law is not a mehram for me, is jamaat still possible ?

Answer (score 1):

**"I pray right behind my brother in law."** - You should pray behind the men leaving space if possible and ***not*** **"right behind"** your brother in law.

[image]

As to the last part of your question, I recommend asking it as a separate question because the answer may depend on individual circumstances as to whether he stays with y'all, is visiting, how big the house is, are there any other females in the house who at this instance were not present etc